# Solving $(3 {Q} {s^{2}})/(100h (h^{2} - 3hs + 3s^{2}))$ for $h$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$Y = \frac{3 \times{Q} \times{s^{2}}}{100h \left(h^{2} - 3hs + 3s^{2}\right)}$$

where Q, s, and h are different variables.

The question I have is how to re-arrange this equation in terms of h?

So far, I have

$$Y = \frac{3 \times{Q} \times{s^{2}}}{100h^{3} - 300h^{2}s + 300hs^{2}}$$

$$Y = \frac{3Qs^{2}}{100h^{3} - 300h^{2}s + 300hs^{2}}$$

$$100h^{3}Y - 300h^{2}sY + 300hs^{2}Y = 3Qs^{2} $$

$$100h^{3} - 300h^{2}s + 300hs^{2} = \frac{3Qs^{2}}{Y} $$

$$\frac{1}{3}h^{3} - h^{2}s + hs^{2} = \frac{3Qs^{2}}{300Y} $$

$$\frac{1}{3}h^{3} - h^{2}s + hs^{2} = \frac{3Qs^{2}}{300Y} $$

now I'm stuck... where do I go from here?

I'm not sure what to do with s not being in the first term on the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your last result: If you multiply by 3 the left hand side is nearly the complete power $(h-s)^3$, here are the single steps to solve for $h$:
$$\frac{1}{3}h^{3} - h^{2}s + hs^{2} = \frac{3Qs^{2}}{300Y} $$

$$h^{3} - 3h^{2}s + 3hs^{2} = \frac{9Qs^{2}}{300Y} $$
$$h^{3} - 3h^{2}s + 3hs^{2}-s^3 + s^3 = \frac{9Qs^{2}}{300Y} $$

$$(h-s)^3 + s^3 = \frac{9Qs^{2}}{300Y} $$
$$(h-s)^3 = \frac{9Qs^{2}}{300Y} - s^3 $$
$$h-s = \left(\frac{9Qs^{2}}{300Y} - s^3\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$h = s +\left(\frac{9Qs^{2}}{300Y} - s^3\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Note: If would be easier to use the idea with the original equation.

Comment: How would you do this from the original equation?

Comment: Multiply by the $h$ terms and divide by $Y$
$$Y = \frac{3 \times{Q} \times{s^{2}}}{100h \left(h^{2} - 3hs + 3s^{2}\right)}$$

$$h\left(h^{2} - 3hs + 3s^{2}\right) = \frac{3 \times{Q} \times{s^{2}}}{100 Y}$$

$$(h-s)^3 + s^3 = \frac{3 \times{Q} \times{s^{2}}}{100 Y}$$